# How to access unity specific same type component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the right way to do this?

Here is my code but I don't think that this is right way to do it

```
public class buttons : MonoBehaviour {

    public Button play;
    public Button shop;
    public Button exit;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Button bplay=play.GetComponent<Button>();
        Button bshop=shop.GetComponent<Button>();
        Button bexit=exit.GetComponent<Button>();
        bplay.onClick.AddListener(()=>loads("level"));
        bshop.onClick.AddListener(()=>loads("shop"));
        bexit.onClick.AddListener(()=>loads("exit"));


    }
    void loads(System.String scenename)
    {
        if(scenename=="level")
        Application.LoadLevel("level_1");
        else if(scenename=="shop")
            Application.LoadLevel("Shop_menu");
        else if(scenename=="exit")
            Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is everything you did in the `Start()` function. The `play`, `shop` and `exit` variables are already `Button` type. There is no need to perform all the `GetComponent` you did in the `Start()` function. Those are *redundant*. You can simply use that public variable directly: `play.onClick.AddListener`.

Secondly, it would be good to compare the instance of the `Button` instead of `string` as that is faster. To do that, you should make the loads function take `Button` as parameter instead of `string`.

Also, the `Application.LoadLevel` function is now deprecated. The `SceneManager.LoadScene` should now be used to load new scene. Make sure to include `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` at the top so that you can use `SceneManager.LoadScene`.

Finally, registering to an event should be done in the `OnEnable` function. You should also un-register it in the `OnDisable` function with the `Button.onClick.RemoveListener` function.

```
public class buttons : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button play;
    public Button shop;
    public Button exit;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        play.onClick.AddListener(() => loads(play));
        shop.onClick.AddListener(() => loads(shop));
        exit.onClick.AddListener(() => loads(exit));
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        play.onClick.RemoveListener(() => loads(play));
        shop.onClick.RemoveListener(() => loads(shop));
        exit.onClick.RemoveListener(() => loads(exit));
    }

    void loads(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == play)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("level_1");
        else if (buttonPressed == shop)
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Shop_menu");
        else if (buttonPressed == exit)
            Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I think that function is a little bit useless, unless you are going to override it or some kind i just do something like play.onClick.AddListener(() =>  SceneManager.LoadScene("level_1"));

Comment: @JuanBayonaBeriso Thanks. In the future, OP may want to do *more* things when the Button is pressed. For example, save before before `Application.Quit();` or disconnected from network. It becomes ugly when you have to cram all those actions into lambda expression.

Comment: Also, if you write so many code in the `AddListener` function, you will have to write that-same code in the `RemoveListener` function. In this case, you have doubled that code by simply not using a function.